# How to retrieve data using useState from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have few React Components :

***MainPage.jsx***

```
import Hotels from "./Hotels";
import WelcomePage from "./WelcomePage";

import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js";
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-firestore.js";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { useState } from "react";

function MainPage() {
  const [hotels, getHotels] = useState([]);

  async function fetchHotels() {
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCHr3-x82i4RcGewtRs3XQ02Ps15Vm6ukQ",
      authDomain: "webapp-48b9a.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "webapp-48b9a",
      storageBucket: "webapp-48b9a.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "889223227604",
      appId: "1:889223227604:web:aca93f8aa7b031fdfe7341",
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "reviews"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      hotels.push(doc.data());
    });
    console.log(hotels);
  }

  fetchHotels();

  return (
    <main className="content">
      <Hotels hotels={hotels} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default MainPage;
```

***Hotels.jsx***

```
import Hotel from "./Hotel";

function Hotels(props) {
  const { hotels = [] } = props;

  return (
    <div className="Hotels">
      {hotels.map((hotel, id) => (
        <Hotel key={id} {...hotel} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hotels;
```

***Hotel.jsx***

```
function Hotel(props) {
  const { name, img, localization, stars, review, author } = props;

  return (
    <div className="Hotel_card">
      <h2 className="Hotel_name">{name}</h2>
      <img className="Hotel_img" src={img} alt="hotel_img" />
      <h3 className="Hotel_localization">{localization}</h3>
      <p className="Hotel_stars">{stars}</p>
      <p className="Hotel_review">{review}</p>
      <h5 className="Hotel_author">Wroten by {author}</h5>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hotel;
```

***Nothing is displayed right now because Hotel.jsx doesn't see the data.
console.log(hotels) in MainPage.jsx outputs this object***

[console.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS8no.png)

***Question - How to display the data?***

***I guess I'm using useState incorrectly because Hostel.jsx doesn't receive any data***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shout put `fetchHotels()` in `useEffect`:

replace

```
fetchHotels();
```

with

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchHotels();
}, []);
```

Then, You can not push to react state array directly,

replace

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    hotels.push(doc.data());
});
```

with:

```
let list = [];
await querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   list.push(doc.data());
});
getHotels(list);
```

Finally, you have another error in

```
<h3 className="Hotel_localization">{hotel.localization}</h3>
```

`localization` is an object.
`Objects are not valid as a React child`

So, it should be:

```
<h3 className="Hotel_localization">
    {localization._lat}, {localization._long}
</h3>
```

Or something like that

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-kate-7cmu3s

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass props like this : `{...hotel}`

Try this:

```
 <div className="Hotels">
      {hotels.map((hotel, id) => (
       return <Hotel key={id} hotel={hotel} />
      ))}
    </div>
```

and in your component get the prop hotel and from there pass the data :

```
function Hotel(props) {
  const { hotel } = props;

  return (
    <div className="Hotel_card">
      <h2 className="Hotel_name">{hotel.name}</h2>
      <img className="Hotel_img" src={hotel.img} alt="hotel_img" />
      <h3 className="Hotel_localization">{hotel.localization}</h3>
      <p className="Hotel_stars">{hotel.stars}</p>
      <p className="Hotel_review">{hotel.review}</p>
      <h5 className="Hotel_author">Wroten by {hotel.author}</h5>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error (return is highlighted in red)

Comment: so sometring is misspelled somewhere. it's don't say that the code isn't right

Answer (score 0):

In React you can NOT mutate the state directly or it won't be able to listen to the changes on the state and re-render the component accordingly to the changes. So, in the **fetchHotels** function once you fetch the data you need to use the setState method provided by the react state to update the hotels state correctly:

```
const _hotels = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
 _hotels.push(doc.data());
});
getHotels(_hotels); //change the name of the method to setHotels to be more explicative
```